# Discrete time Markov chain, help needed!

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> A machine consists of $K$ components in series, i.e., all the
>   components must be in working condition for the machine to be
>   functional. When the machine is functional at the beginning of the
>   $n$th day, each component has a probability $p$ of failing at the
>   beginning of the next day, independent of other components. (More than
>   one component can fail at the same time).
>
> When the machine fails, a single repair person repairs the failed
>   components one by one. It takes exactly one day to repair one failed
>   component. When all the failed components are repaired the machine is
>   functional again, and behaves as before. When the machine is down, the
>   working components do not fail.
>
> Let $X_n$ be the number of failed components at the beginning of the
>   $n$th day, after all the failure and repair events at that time are
>   accounted for. Show that $\{X_n, n>0\}$ is a Discrete time Markov chain.
>   Display the transition matrix or the transition diagram.

I don't know how to start this problem. 
I didn't understand the problem.

Comment: Assuming $n $ components work on a given day, what is the distribution of the number that fail that day? This will give you most of the information about the transition matrix.

Comment: Is the number n<K here ?

Comment: I intend $n \leq K $, yes.

Comment: @Ian, I have been trying this problem, but failed to understand it. Can you elaborate  it?

Comment: So there are $K+1$ states depending on how many components are functional. When $K$ components function, Binomial($K,p$) components fail. In other words you go from $X_n=K$ to $X_{n+1}=K-B$ where $B \sim$ Binomial($K,p$). Otherwise one component is repaired, so you go from $X_n=a$ to $X_{n+1}=a+1$. (Sorry about my first comment, I missed the "components do not fail when the machine is down" statement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have
$$
X_{n+1} = \begin{cases}
X_n + 1,& 1\leqslant X_n< K\\
V_{n+1}, & X_n = K,
\end{cases}
$$
where the sequence $\{V_n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$ is independent with $\operatorname{Bin}(K,1-p)$ distribution. Since $X_{n+1} = f(X_n, V_{n+1})$ where $V_{n+1}$ is independent of the $X_n$, we readily see that $\{X_n:n=0,1,\ldots\}$ satisfies the Markov property. The transition probabilities are given by
$$
p_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
1,& j=i+1,\ 0<i<K\\
\binom K {j-1} (1-p)^{j-1} p^{K-j+1},& i=K,\ 0<j<i\\
(1-p)^K + K(1-p)^{K-1}p,& i=j=K.
\end{cases}
$$
The subtlety here is that there are two ways the system can transition from $i$ to $j$ - either there are no failures, or there is exactly one failure (in which case it is repaired in that same period).